# Converting Firebase Listview to Firestore Listview

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am in the process of converting my app from firebase to Firestore due to the filters i need to apply and cannot do on Realtime Database.

I have a custom listview which works perfectly according to the code below using firebase. i have replicated the structure in Firestore so make life easier but can't seem to get the listview to Work on Firestore.

```
val dealRef = ref.child("Deal_Summary2").orderByChild("buyer_id").equalTo(userid)
    dealRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if(p0!!.exists()){
                summarylist.clear()
                for (e in p0.children){
                    val deal = e.getValue(DealSummary::class.java)

                    summarylist.add(deal!!)

                }

                val adapter = Mydeals_buyer_adapter(applicationContext,
                    R.layout.mydeals_buyer_listview,
                    summarylist


                )
                listview.adapter=adapter

            }

        }

    })
```

I seem to be stuck in extracting the documents from Firestore and storing the values into my model class **DealSummary::class.java**.

I can't seem to find any examples in doing this online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

docref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

```
    docref.collection("Deal_Summary2").whereEqualTo("buyer_id", userid).get()
        .addOnCompleteListener() { task ->

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                val summary = ArrayList<DealSummary>()

                for (document in task.result!!) {


                    summarylist.add(document.toObject(DealSummary::class.java))

                }

                val adapter = Mydeals_buyer_adapter(
                    applicationContext,
                    R.layout.mydeals_buyer_listview,
                    summarylist


                )
                listview.adapter = adapter


            } else {

                Log.d("Firestore_error", "No Data")
            }
```